# Low-valued multivariate integral in R

Tags: r, density-function, logarithm, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate multivariate normal integrals in R, with relatively high dimensions. I've tried the *openMX* and *cubature* packages. The problem is that the integrals become too small and I get zeroes as a solution, because of the numerical characteristics of the machine. One way to fix that would be to have the integral function return the log value of the integral (for example similar to *dnorm*(...,log = T)). Does such a function exist? Or is there another way I can solve this problem? For now I approximated those integrals by taking the density in the middle of the intervals, but that can result in severe errors.
Below is an example with *openMX*, which returns 0, while the MVN density clearly is not zero (but is very small). In this example I'm trying to integrate over intervals of size 1 around my_vec:

```
library(openMX)
my_vec   <- c(10, 25, 20, 18, 23, 30, 12, 24, 21)
mean_vec <- c(13, 20, 20, 10, 29, 25, 10, 11, 24)
Sigma    <- diag(rep(0.05, 9))
omxMnor(Sigma, mean_vec, lbound = my_vec - 0.5, ubound = my_vec + 0.5)
     [,1]
[1,]    0
```

This is just an example. In reality there's a possibility of a non-diagonal covariance matrix, so just integrating over univariate normals would not be possible.

Comment: Could you post some examples of such integrals and what you have done sofar?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added an example.

Comment: I wonder whether you might be better off either (a) on a programming site, or (b) recasting this as a mathematical problem about how to re-express your integrals and then posting on a maths site.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks, I'll try that. I've noticed that most of the packages have a log option for density calculation, but no log option for probability calculation (which is what I'm calculating). Any idea why that might be?

Comment: First, represent an integral as a Riemann sum, take the logarithm ... Do you see any simplifications? logs of products simplify, logs of sums do not as far as I know ... That's probably the reason.  Such an option, at best, would have to be considered on a case basis, so is not available for general functions.